# Ldap Query to return sub tree only if parent condition is true

Tags: ldap-query

I'm trying to write a search filter that return results of a sub tree, only if the parent tree meets certain condition... is it possible?

I have the following structure:

```
ou=ftp
   domainName=example.com
       ou=users
          uid=firstUser
          uid=secondUser
   domainName=otherdomain.com
       ou=users
          uid=othertUser
          uid=otherdUser
```

In domainName=example.com I have an atrribute accountStatus that can be "active" or  "inactive".

I want to return the users only if accountStatus is "active".

I tried to do a composite filter as follows:

```
(&(&(objectclass=mailDomain)(accountStatus=active))(&(uid=*)(objectclass=posixAccount)))
```

objectclass=mailDomain and accountStatus=active belongs to the parent tree. 
The query does not return any results, because it search all the attributes at the same level.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

While you can configure the search space to be a subtree, a list or even a single entry, a search filter is always applied to each single entry of the result set.  This usually influences the design of the directory information tree, and the schema as well.

Stay away from "normalization" and make attributes available at the user entry instead of some parent node.  You greatly increase the overall value of your directory that way, allowing simple LDAP clients to leverage the information in your directory.